# How to create a layout like BBC Featured Content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I really like the new BBC layout and in particular the featured content bit where you can scroll left and right, with elements not in the main view faded out, see http://www.bbc.co.uk/.

Just wondering if anyone knows how they developed this and how to make something similar?

Comment: Search for html carousel on google. Nivo slider is one popular implementation of this.

Comment: found exactly what I wanted at http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/ (after much searching) hope this helps some others out

Comment: (This is too broad for Stack Overflow).